# React/Bootstrap: How to implement hovering effect class like Tailwind's :hover

Tags: reactjs, hover, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

What is the Bootstrap way of Tailwind's hover in React? I cannot seem to find any on google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like `hover:` for Bootstrap. You have to use CSS.